# How to test a dll using cppunit

Tags: unit-testing, dll, cppunit

I want to test a Dll using cppunit. I have created a testcase dll. I have linked the .lib file to my testcase dll. I am calling the function to be tested from my testcase dll. But when iam trying to compile the testcase dll, it is giving linker error(for the function to be tested). Do I need to export all the functions that I need to unit test?

I am new to CPPUNIT. Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's not related with CppUnit. to use something outside of dynamic library you need to export it. possible solution is to have statically-linked library with all your code. this lib can be tested by testcase.dll w/o any exports. and simple wrapper.dll over your static.lib that exports only required stuff